# Why Stirling formula at n = -1 and n= -2 is so close to 2*pi*i

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function, pi

We know asymptotic formula for gamma function as Stirling formula
$$\Gamma(z+1) \approx F(z+1) = \sqrt{2\pi z}\left({\cfrac{z}{e}}\right)^z\cdot \left({1+\cfrac{1}{12z} +\cfrac{1}{288z^2}+...}\right)$$
The value of $\Gamma(0)$ and $\Gamma(-1)$ is of course infinity, but
$$F(0) = -2\pi i\cdot (1+3.07...\cdot 10^{-3})$$
$$F(-1) = +2\pi i\cdot (1+3.9...\cdot 10^{-7})$$
is it a coincidence or something is connected to this?

Comment: Isn’t the Stirling Approximation just $$F(x)=\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac xe\right)^x$$? giving $$F(-1)=-i e\sqrt{2\pi}=6.81\not≈2\pi$$

Comment: I mean $$F(x,N) = \sqrt{2 \pi x} \left( { \cfrac{x}{e}} \right)^x \cdot e^{ \sum_{i=1}^N{\cfrac{B_{2i}}{2i(2i-1)x^{2i-1} } } }$$

Comment: I used $F(-1,N=4)$ and $F(-2,N=7)$ (the row really diverges and i used finit members)